# How to pass parameter in onclick in Thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

I am passing arrayList but onclick is passing parameter a string in javascript function. How can iget an array instead of string

```
<div class="card" th:data-work="${top.section}" onclick="showData(this.dataset.work)">
```

In console window its printing string but i had passed array i dont know how its get converted into string.

```
const activityModal  = (work) => {
        console.log(typeof work) // string  
        console.log(work) //[com.example.working.Foobar@7r6r8e]
        console.log(work[0]) // [

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The content of the `data-work` attribute in the div is a string representation of whatever is returned by `${top.section}`. So, in your case that looks like this:

```
<div class="card" 
     data-work="[com.example.working.Foobar@7r6r8e]" 
     onclick="showData(this.dataset.work)">some content</div>
```

That `[com.example.working.Foobar@7r6r8e]` is the result of calling the `toString()` method on each of your `Foobar` objects in the ArrayList, when Thymeleaf processes the template.

Therefore, to get useful data in the div, you need to override the `toString()` method in your `Foobar` class.

Furthermore, you need to override it in a way which will provide a usable representation of the data in each `Foobar` instance.

In my tiny test case, I only have one field in my test class, so I did this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "{ \"amount\":" + amount + "}";
}
```

I chose to format the data as JSON, so that it would be easier to handle by JavaScript.

Now, the div looks something like this (in my case):

```
<div class="card" 
     data-work="[{ &quot;amount&quot;:123}, { &quot;amount&quot;:456}]" 
     onclick="showData(this.dataset.work)">click me!</div>
```

In the `showData` function on my page, I have this:

```
function showData(work) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(work))
}
```

This shows that my data has been parsed from a string back into a JavaScript array containing two JS objects (because I placed 2 objects in my ArrayList):

[image]

**Be careful how you choose to override `toString()` - or if you even should.**

You may prefer to **have a separate method** which generates a string representation of `Foobar` just to pass to your template. You may not want the canonical string representation of your class to be determined by the needs of your web page.

They (`toString` and your stringifier) should probably be kept as separate formats, since they serve very different purposes.

(Also if you do choose to use JSON as the representation you pass to Thymeleaf, use a library to build it - don't be lazy like I was in my tiny demo: don't use string concatenation.)